# How do I access data on my EBS Volume from R-Studio Server on Ubuntu EC2 Instance

Tags: r, ssh, amazon-ec2, amazon-s3, rstudio

Not a programming question but definitely related to big data analysis.

I have setup R-Studio Server on an Ubuntu EC2 instance for the first time and successfully started r-studio server in my browser. I also have putty ssh client.

I had a file in an s3 bucket. I passed this command to bring it from s3 to my ebs volume:

`s3cmd get s3://data-analysis/input-data/filename.csv` . I assume this command downloads the file from s3 into the ebs volume.

1) How do I set path in r-studio server to my mounted EBS volume 
2) Why do I not see the contents of my EBS volume in the r-studio files area (bottom right side? ) .

I also tried to list the contents of my volume in the ssh using this:

```
$ ls /dev/xvdal
```

I have scoured the internet looking for help on this but not found the nuts and bolts detail for this problem anywhere. Please help!

Comment: Did you resolve this?

Comment: yes I did - you just have to move the file in EBS volume into your user directory on the linux command line. The moment i did that, the file was showing in my r-studio files area. I don't remember the exact command - it was something like `sudo cp filename.csv ~username/`

Comment: quick google search yielded this useful linke: https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/758119-moving-files-linux-commands-file-managers

Comment: Thanks. I already made a shortcut link to my ebs in the relevant folder :). Unfortunately I now also have this error...: https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/200661766-RStudio-server-issues-Error-occurred-during-transmission

Comment: There is no easy way to work with RStudio in AWS ! Try Microsoft Cortana - owing to Microsoft's acquisition of Revolution, their integration with R is likely stronger.